# Table of Contents just contains lots of "New Article N" entries

Tags: kindle, creation, table-of-contents

I'm using QuarkXPress 2017 to create a Kindle ebook based on a print layout that someone else has created for commercial printing. Everything's going fine apart from the Table of Contents; when I load the .mobi file into KDP and preview it the TOC just holds a load of entries saying "New Article N" where N ranges from 1 to 30 (though not every number in between, 25 in total).

I assume it's generated automatically from the titles of each article or story in the document, which were set to defaults when they were first created, but I can't see any way to rename them. I've searched through Help and Googled loads but I'm still none the wiser.

Same issue occurs when I generate an EPUB and open it as a ZIP - the nav.xhtml file has the same entries in it as I see on the preview of the .mobi file so I doubt it's an issue with the previewer.

Any ideas?

Comment: While the problem is almost certainly with Quark, in a pinch you could simply unzip the epub, edit the nav.xhtml manually with the right information, rezip and change extension to .epub again, use Kindle previewer to export to mobi and then you're done.

Comment: I understand that this is not an ideal situation, but it is fairly common for me to do some post-processing.

Comment: Thanks @idiotprogrammer - that's certainly a possible last resort. Or maybe not so last :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a great deal more searching around, I found the answer in a manual for an earlier version of QuarkXPress.

You have to open the Reflow palette, where you get a list of all the articles making up the reflow layout - and the names matched the entries I was getting in the TOC. But to edit them you have to select them and click the edit button in the palette toolbar, there's no right click menu for this.

In any case, I never finished this as I decided it was easier to export the original PDF to Word, clean it up, define the TOC and upload that to Amazon instead...